# Nesting CSS Classes?

Tags: css, angularjs, class, css-selectors, nested

So reading up on some angular and CSS and I forget what exactly this means

```
.css-form input.ng-invalid.ng-touched { color: whatever; }
```

I know that it's selecting the input elements nested inside the `css-form` class, but what about when something has like `div.a` or something? Is that just saying the `div` with class `a`?

I'm guessing this would be the `input` that has class `ng-invalid` and `ng-touched` (and they seem to be set automatically by angular, you don't actually put them in brackets as it looks)

Is this call correct about nesting?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe your understanding is correct. You can always try it out and see what happens if you're not entirely certain of what the rules are.

Comment: CSS is fun to play with because you can always reverse a change you made that did not work out. CSS styles all your pages so go bonkers and find out all the great stuff it can do.

Answer (score 2):

```
.css-form input.ng-invalid.ng-touched { color: whatever; }
```

This selector is saying:

> Target input elements whose class attribute contains the following two
>   values:
>
> - `ng-invalid`
> - `ng-touched`
>
> In addition, the input must be a descendant of an element with class
>   `css-form`

Sample HTML:

```
<form class="css-form">
    <input class="ng-invalid">
    <input class="ng-touched">
    <input class="ng-invalid ng-touched">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The CSS rule above would target the third `input` only.

Note that the class selectors must be chained together (i.e., touching). If there were to be even one character of whitespace, it would become a descendant selector instead.

```
.css-form input.ng-invalid .ng-touched { color: whatever; }
```

This selector says:

> Target elements with class `ng-touched` that are descendants of input elements with class `ng-invalid`, that are descendants of elements with class `css-form`.
>
> *("descendants of input elements.." LOL. I know. It's just an example, and we're talking CSS, and it's late, and I'm trying to make a point goddamit! ... ;-)*

W3C References:

- [6.4. Class selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html)
- [8.1. Descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is "CSS selectors", those are patterns used to select the element(s) you want to style.

`div.a` can be explained that selects all `div` elements with `class="a"`

You can refer to [w3school - CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for full details.